# PYTHON / XLWINGS - Very basic step: how to get scripts to work inside excel

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm trying to understand how to get 'mymodule.py' from the quickstart to work inside my excel. My question is, where do I put the mymodule.py so that excel/xlwings can call it correctly? That is not clear, to me, from the docs. How can I get to read .py from other files. I tried messing around with the following:

PYTHON_MAC: This is the directory of the Python interpreter on Mac OSX. "" resolves to your default installation as per PATH on .bash_profile. To get special folders on Mac, type GetMacDir("Name") where Name is one of the following: Home, Desktop, Applications, Documents.

But to no success. In reality I have not understood where I should change the settings? In the VBA file?

Thanks in advance - I'm new to python...

Answer (score 0):

Python looks for files on certain paths according to the [module-search-path-docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). Per default, the xlwings VBA module adds the path of the Workbook to this path (i.e. it expects the source file to be in the same directory as the Workbook). This is happening (or can be changed to where your python file is) on this line in the VBA settings `PYTHONPATH = ThisWorkbook.Path` and is explained [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/vba.html#settings). `PYTHON_MAC` is the location of the python interpreter, you shouldn't need to change that if you go with something like the [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) distribution, which I would recommend on Mac.

Comment: If i have the .py file and the worksheet in the same archive, it should be good then right?

Comment: If i want to change where I want to store my python scripts I have to change inside the xlwings the setting PYTHONPATH = ThisWorkbook.Path to PYTHONPATH = 'user\programs\python'  lets say? Thanks

Comment: Sounds about right, but make sure it's a valid VBA string with double-quotes.